# Did the impact calculation changed recently?

Tags: discussion, people-reached

Not that the estimated impact that I have here matters but I noticed a drop from `~191k` on Friday to `173k` now `(-10%)` without any reputation change.

Did the algorithm change? Or is there something else that could have affected the value?

Comment: Did one of your answers or questions recently get deleted?

Comment: @Cerbrus This would have cause a rep change, wouldn't it?

Comment: Not necessarily. When a answer is old enough, rep gained from it won't be lost, where it to be deleted. (I'm not familiar with the exact rules. 60 days or something, it was)

Comment: @Cerbrus then where can I find the information ?

Comment: I found [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/).

Comment: I think it's possible for your impact to decrease if another answer gets upvotes (or yours gets downvotes) such that your answer is no longer one of the top N answers on a question.

Comment: I was on ~110K, now it is ~62K. Wonder what happened!

Comment: Maybe your one of your top 3, <5 score answer got surpassed by another one so it is not top 3 anymore?