# How did I reach so many people overnight?

Tags: discussion, people-reached

Friday, 12.2, I had **16k** people reached which is completely normal if I check out my activity on SO.

Today, I've logged in into my account and noticed this:

[image: ~326k people reached]

Is this some kind of glitch? How can it be that I got +310k on my total impact (in almost 3 days if so), I didn't post that good answer in friday when I last saw my profile. What caused this kind of behaviour?

Thanks.

EDIT:

This link [**here**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here) helped me to understand the reach rules. I didn't know that.

Comment: Maybe you got famous?

Comment: not THAT famous. :)

Comment: Someone upvoted one of your answers on a highly-viewed question (or downvoted an answer that was above yours).  The impact stat doesn't care when you posted the answer -- all the views from whenever the question was posted are counted as people reached.

Comment: That's not a case. From 10.2 I had only +50 reputation change and that was all from this question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217170/seo-ca-or-com-for-a-canadian-international-website/35359080#35359080

Comment: [Someone else was confused about sudden changes in their impact](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315383/did-the-impact-calculation-changed-recently).  Maybe there should be an impact breakdown by question/answer.

Comment: Derived from this [MSE question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273828): You got an upvote on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32583740/3933332) on [Feb 10](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32583740/timeline), and the question has over 300k views. So you got these 300k people in seconds :) (See more about 'people reached': http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244534)

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32583740/4099593) got upvoted by 1  -->  answer got 4 votes --> became top 3 best --> More helpful --> More famous \o/

Comment: wow, this is insane. I didn't know that reach works like that. (if it works like that).

Comment: @Bhargav Exactly. Care to post that as an answer? Linking to the canonical information on the global Meta (provided by Rizier) would also be helpful.

Comment: Look on the bright side - you should now be able to get a highly-paid job in advertising.

Comment: @DeDuplicator, it didn't doubled it 20bled.

Comment: Sure, the exact multiplier is different.

Comment: @CodyGray It's a dupe, so answer is not required :-)