# What happened to reach?

Tags: support

So..

First I noticed is this behavoiour and I've asked a question:

[How did I reach so many people overnight?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316886/how-did-i-reach-so-many-people-overnight)

Today, it's reversed situation which means that my reach fell for 300k.

What's wrong with reach, and is this some kind of bug?

**BEFORE - AFTER**:

[image] [image: BEFORE]

Comment: It's probably the opposite: Either you got a downvote for an answer that had >= 5 votes, or the post was deleted.

Comment: nope, it's still here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php/32583740#32583740

Comment: But its score is < 5.

Comment: but, it isn't edited, and no one downvoted on it.

Comment: Maybe the user who upvoted you deleted his account.

Comment: Relevant background that explains how and why that silly number works: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php/32583740#32583740) of yours lost one of its upvotes (probably because one of the accounts that upvoted you was deleted), you became less famous. But don't worry, good answers will be soon or later upvoted, and you'll reach more and more people.

Edit: You've just got your 5<sup>th</sup> upvote, you're famous again.

Comment: Hah, thanks mate. I didn't know that reach is affected by users who get deleted.