# Why is my "Impact and people reached" fluctuating?

Tags: discussion, support, people-reached

I do understand that the "People reached" number is a rough estimate of how many views all your answers, comments or questions have, and that this number can jump a little bit, caused by up- and down votes. It is fairly explained in this [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290491/4746087). But last days, my personal "people reached" number dropped from 140k to 16k. After two days, it is peaking again at 186k. Not a small difference in my humble opinion.

Any explanation?

Comment: Related [question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320515/what-happened-to-reach).

Comment: You have an [answer on a question with 100K+ views](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34358545/250725).  Recent activity on the post (new answers, deleted answers, surge of voting, etc) will impact the score as mentioned in the post you linked.  You probably lost credit for that answer, then got it back.