# How is it possible that the number of people reached is dropping down?

Tags: bug, people-reached

My number of estimated people reached with helpful answers has dropped down from 55k to 41K in a day. How is it even possible ?

Comment: People die every day. As do bad questions.

Comment: Either a post of yours got deleted for some reason, or your score on an answer dropped to 1, which means the system stopped counting it towards your "reached"

Comment: Looking through stuff, this might not be as simple as what comments suggest folks - leaving the bug tag here.

Comment: @TimPost I mean, there are many entirely plausible ways for the number to go down, and I'd expect it to happen rather often for anyone with a lot of answers.  It's certainly far and away the more likely option, even if there being a bug isn't impossible.

Comment: @CodyGray yeah but this number is supposed to consider only helpful answers. Hard to have helpful answer if the question is bad, no ?

Comment: @Patrice I taught about that, I saw you last time on a previous post, but it happened way before I got a post removed, I just took the time to ask now. That's why I wonder, I haven't seen any of my posts being removed when it happened

Comment: @Guillaume. Oh for sure it's possible that there is indeed a bug.   Normally when my reach goes down it's because one of my answers lost an upvote or got a downvote. It brings the score to 1, and "takes" the reach from that post.

Comment: Probably other answers overtook yours on this question.https://stackoverflow.com/q/38462885/73226. If you move out of the top 3 you lose those views https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320520/73226 and two answers posted in June are above yours.

Comment: @GuillaumeLeMière The stat doesn't consider a questions quality, only it's views.

Comment: The definition is "Estimadok number of times people viewed your helpful posts (based on page views of your questions and questions where you wrote highly-ranked answers). Stackoverflow shouldn't remove questions views on a question remove. A view has been made, it is a fact, removing it is an error of logic, I think.

Comment: @GuillaumeLeMière the number is essentially [SUM(views)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290491/what-does-the-people-reached-signify-and-how-is-it-calculated) on all questions where your answer counts irrespective of age or "views". The number can go wildly up or down depending on whether your answer counts on frequently visited question. There were plenty of posts about ["why my 'reach' doubled overnight"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318853/why-users-reached-increased-exponentially) already... (I think two linked posts combined answer your question)

Comment: (BTW, here is exact duplicate - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315383/did-the-impact-calculation-changed-recently, but it has no answers - so not really useful - but may deserve some duplicate chaining too :) )

Comment: My reaches got down from 70k to 16k. I dont know why?